# Is 993 the only example with such a property in the Collatz sequence?

Tags: collatz-conjecture

Let be N an integer.

$T^{(k)} (N) $ is the 3x+1 function with k the number of iterations.

Starting from N=993, after 65 steps, you reach 130, which is $65\cdot 2$.

Do you believe that there are infinitely many N such that:

$T^{(k)} (N) =2\cdot k$?

Comment: Why this obsession with $993$?  You have posted several very similar questions about it...is there any reason for this?  At a minimum, you should link to all the parallel questions you have been asking.

Answer (score 1):

Pick any $k$ and go backwards $k$ steps from $2k$ to find a suitable $N$ for this $k$. In fact, quite often you have two choices of ging backwards, so you may find many $N$ for your $k$. What always works is $N=2^k\cdot 2k$, of course.

Comment: This depends a bit on how one defines $T$. E.g., if one defines $T(x)$ to be the odd part of $3x+1$, ....